# Dynamically change primary color of an Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to be able to change the primary color of my Ionic app, with a given hex color.

As the primary color is set in the scss files, I think it's impossible to edit this value. Thus, I'd like to know if I could put a directive/attribute on every Ionic element of my pages : for exemple :

```
<ion-tabs color="#FFFFF">
```

color attribute is only working with variables from the scss file

I'd like to find a solution like in this thread :
[Ionic primary color dinamically change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466712/ionic-primary-color-dinamically-change), but the problem is it needs a scss for each theme, and I do not have any theme, just a given hex color string.

Thank you in advance for any response

Comment: any updates on this? @saperlipopette

Comment: Hello, no... But as a workaround I declared about 200 colors in my variable.scss like this :

`$colors: (
  Bisque : #FFE4C4,
  Brown : #A52A2A,
  BurlyWood : #DEB887,
  CadetBlue : #5F9EA0,
  Chocolate : #D2691E,
  Coral : #FF7F50,
  CornflowerBlue : #6495ED,
  Crimson : #DC143C
);`. This way I can change primary color of the app easily, but the final css compilation is very long (about 2 mins), and the final css file is 25Mo+