# Ionic 3 load css from API/Server

Tags: css, ionic3

I have an Ionic application. The data of the application are loaded by web service from a CMS. The user of the CMS can set individual colors. These colors can also be picked up via the web service.
But how can I reload them as CSS in my application?

Answer (score 0):

That is very feasible . You just need to save the color locally and use Color binding or style binding to use it in your UI.

Example:

```
 <ion-icon [style.color]="myCMSColor" name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>

 <div class="circle" [style.background]="myCMSColor">
```

Where `myCMSColor` is a string containing the Hex value of  the user chosen color.

Comment: Thank you, but so I have to set the CSS for each element. I'm looking for a way to override CSS globally. I thought about CSS custom properties, but I do not know how to overwrite them later.

Comment: maybe you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466712/ionic-primary-color-dinamically-change

Comment: One idea is to get the colors via JSON webservice and write them to a local CSS file. : root {- my-color: # ffcc00;}